# Magento2 Cronjob and Generate Schedules Every

Tags: magento2, cron, crontab

I create a custom module, that updates prices and product stock. This is two different jobs in the same cron group.

My `crontab.xml` is:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
<group id="product_update">
   <job name="stock_update_cron" instance="Namespace\ModuleName\Cron\StockCron" method="execute">
        <schedule>0 3 * * 1-5</schedule>
    </job>
    <job name="price_update_cron" instance="Namespace\ModuleName\Cron\PricesCron" method="execute">
        <schedule>0 8 * * 1-5</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
```

I setup each job schedule, to run once a day from Monday to Friday. The stock update, should run at 3h00m from Monday to Friday, and Price update at 8h00m from Monday to Friday.

I create a `cron_group.xml`, but my main question is what value should I insert on "*schedule generate every*" so this two jobs run once a day? I did some test already and, even when I put 1 in "*schedule generate every*", the jobs are not begin scheduled in the `cron_shedule` table.

Anyone knows why? What value should go to "*schedule generate every*", so my jobs can run once a day?

Comment: How often do they run right now?